# Installing Valgrind on a 3.x Kernel

Tags: 11.10, 64-bit, c

I was reading *[Learn C the Hard Way](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/learn-c-the-hard-waych5.html)* when I stumbled upon and followed the instructions for installing Valgrind, the C debugger. However, when I ran `./configure` to setup build configurations, I got

```
checking for the kernel version... unsupported (3.0.0-17-generic)
configure: error: Valgrind works on kernels 2.4, 2.6
```

I am running Ubuntu 11.10, on the kernel Linux 3.0.0-17-generic x86_64.

The answer may be obvious but I'm not acquainted with Linux: **How do I get Valgrind working on my computer?** Thanks.

Comment: I came here from LCTHW too :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Valgrind is installable from repository(tested on 12.04 running kernel 3.2.x).  `sudo apt-get install valgrind`.  Also available in 11.10 according to [this](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/valgrind).

Just an additional note, it's not a debugger.  It's a memory fault detector.

Answer (score 3):

From [LCTHW](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex4.html):

"You could install Valgrind with the package manager for your OS, but I want you to learn to install things from source"

Try a newer version of Valgrind, e.g. 3.10.1